# Zener and Common Diode in series

Tags: diodes, relay, zener

I was looking at a Diagram, and I saw that a relay uses a Zener diode and a common diode in series between the coil ends. In the past I've seen a common diode being used in order to protect the voltage from going to the X1 end (ground), but in this case I don't know what is the purpose. I would really appreciate if someone could help me please.

Thanks.

Comment: Show the circuit! The most probable purpose is to dissipate the coils enery faster, for instance to let a relay fall off faster. Another purpsoe is to limit the volate at the collector in a flyback high-voltage generator.

Comment: I agree with everything @wouter says above

Comment: People seem not to have noted that initial current in zener is Iload at the time of turnoff. With no load dissipation is Vdiode x Iload + Iload^2 x Rcoil. dd the zener and zener dissipation is Iload x Vzener. This is added to the exustiung diode +coil - R dissipation. If say Iloaqd = 1A and Vdiode = 0.8A aqnd Rcoil =  1 Ohm them Ddiode = 0.8W, Dcoil = 1 Watt. Add as eg 12V zener and dissipation Dzener = 12 Watt. This falls as energy dissipates so zener may be able to be lower wattage than it may seem. Depends on total energy to dissipate and frequency of use.

Answer (score 6):

I googled "zener in series with diode across coil" and came up with this circuit: -

[image]

So, if the zener were shorted out what would happen when the transistor open circuits: The current that was formerly flowing into the BJT would flow through the diode and back to the top terminal of the coil. This is a common protection mechanism for relay coils. Without that protection the voltage at the collector would rise to hundreds of volts and punture the collector-base region and this would happen in microseconds.

Yes, the transistor would die but the relay would deactivate very, very quickly because it dissipates the stored magnetic energy very quickly. If, on the other hand, you use a diode (without the zener) the relay will deactivate in several (maybe tens of) milli seconds. It takes this long to deactivate the relay because the energy built up in the coil (i.e. it's magnetic field) isn't naturally converted to heat that quickly when using just a diode.

A diode drops ~0.7 volts and if the relay current is 30mA that's an intial power dissipation of only 21mW.

However, if the zener is added, it effectively makes the diode drop more voltage (say) 10V and the initial power dissipated is more like 300 mW. This means that the relay coil loses its stored energy more quickly and the circulating current in the coil (that keeps making magnetism that keeps the relay activated) is drowned much more quickly.

The upside is that the transistor collector only sees a voltage that is approximately Vcc + 11V and anyone designing this circuit will make sure that the transistor is rated for this slight excess.

Comment: All good stuff. What I did when I had hair was place a 33V Zener between C&E of the drive BJT,This was done on Automotive stuff.What can also be seen with the series zener and the CE zener is that reverse polarity protection is inherent when the zener brakedown voltage is above the supply volts. The CE zener provides good definition of max VCE for transistor protection.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming this is the circuit that Andy is talking about, the reason for the Zener is in part to restore performance but also to [prolong the life of the relay's contacts](http://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=13C3264_AppNote&DocType=CS&DocLang=EN). A simple flyback (while protecting the transistor) can be hard on the relay itself and cause it to become welded by not providing enough force to break open the contacts. From TE's appnote dedicated to this:

[image]

> One very common practice is to simply shunt the coil with a general
>   purpose diode, placing the diode to block the source voltage and conduct
>   with the reverse polarity of the coil induced voltage. This provides a path
>   for the current flowing in the deenergized coil to be externally shunted
>   back into the coil, limiting the magnitude of coil induced voltage to the
>   forward drop of the diode, which the coil current, and resulting magnetic
>   flux, slowly decay (see Fig. 2).
>
> This diode shunt provides maximum protection to the solid state switch,
>   but may have very adverse effects on the switching capability of the
>   relay. It is important to realize that the net force available to cause the
>   armature to open is the difference between the magnetic restraining
>   forces and the spring opening forces, that each of these is varying in a
>   manner to cause the net force to vary both with time and armature
>   position. It is this net force which gives rise to the armature system
>   velocity and energy of momentum as it attempts to effect armature and
>   contact spring transfer.
>
> A slowly decaying magnetic flux (the slowest is experienced with a simple
>   diode shunt across the coil) means the least net force integral available
>   to accelerate the armature open. In fact, rapid loss of the opening forces
>   supplied by stiff NO contact springs, coupled with slowly decaying
>   magnetic forces, can actually cause a period of net force reversal where
>   the armature velocity is slowed, stopped, or even momentarily
>   reversed until the flux further decays, finally permitting available spring
>   “return” forces to cause transfer to continue.
>
> It is equally important to realize that when the contacts of a typical power
>   relay make, connecting very fast rising (e.g., resistive) medium or high
>   current loads to the voltage source, a minute molten interface occurs
>   between the mating contacts, giving rise to a microweld or stick condition
>   that must be separated at the next opening transfer.
>   The “stick” force is normally well within the ability of the net opening
>   force, aided by the momentum of the moving armature, to break the
>   stick and effect contact transfer. However, the loss or even reversal of
>   armature velocity (under conditions of simple diode shunting as described
>   above), and accompanying loss of armature momentum needed to help
>   break the contact stick, can result in failure to break the stick, and a
>   contact “weld” is experienced.
>   The more rapidly the coil current decays, the less the magnetic hold
>   back, and thus the greater the armature momentum and contact stick
>   “break-ability.”
>
> Obviously, this is optimized when no suppression is used. However,
>   near optimum decay rate can be obtained by using a Zener diode in
>   series with a general purpose diode. When the coil source is interrupted,
>   the coil current is shunted through this series arrangement, maintaining
>   a voltage equal to the Zener voltage (plus forward diode drop) until the
>   coil energy is dissipated. This is illustrated in Fig. 3.

Comment: That's a very valid point +1

Answer (score 1):

The diode is blocking the zener in forward conduction mode, while zener and diode both are conducting when \$V > V_{zener}+0.7V\$. The purpose is to dump the inductive energy faster as using the flyback dide only:
\$Tau = L/R\$, so if parallel to the inductor there is a flywheeling diode which has low forward resistance, the current will circulate quite a long time. Suppose you have a large electromechanical brake, when you disconnect the supply the current will circulate with decay constant \$Tau=L/R\$. Now if you apply a larger resistance the decay time shortens, that's why zener or varistor is used, but varistor can accept only a finite numbers of shots.

Comment: Correct. I used to work with large scale relay logic and we used resistors and diodes to slow down relay drop-out to give time for the hand-on of status from one relay to another. Decreasing R gave increasing delay with R=0 giving the max. The diode provides the 'short-circuit' when required. As others have noted this technique does slow the contacts opening so arcing and shorter life may be a problem. Adding the zener reduces the delay and speeds contact movement.

Comment: I have used two transistors to drive the relay coil like a two switch foward convertor clamping flyback to the rail.